# Equivalent norms on Sobolev spaces. Only function and last derivative needed to define the norm.

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Equip $W_n^{p}[0,1]$ with the norm

$$\left\|f\right\|_{W_n^{p}} = \sum_{k=0}^{n}\left\|f^{(k)}\right\|_{L^p}.$$

I want to prove that this norm is equivalent to the norm
$$\left\|f\right\|_2 = \left\|f\right\|_{L^p}+\left\|f^{(n)}\right\|_{L^p}.$$

It is obvious that $\left\|f\right\|_2\leq \left\|f\right\|_{W_n^p}$ so I want to find a constant $C>0$ such that $\left\|f\right\|_{W_n^p}\leq C\left\|f\right\|_2$. I've managed to solve this in the case $n=2$ but I don't know how to generalize this to the case $n>2$.

> **Solution in the case $n=2$:**
>   Let $f\in W^{2}_p[0,1]$. Let $\xi_{\mathrm{min}}$ and $\xi_{\mathrm{min}}'$ be points which minimizes $|f|$ and $|f'|$ respectively. Note that these functions are continuous so these points exists. Now Hölder's inequality implies that
>       \begin{align*}
>   |f'(x)|& = \left|f'(\xi_{\mathrm{min}}')+\int_{\xi_{\mathrm{min}}'}^{x}f''(t)\, dt\right| \\
>   & \leq |f'(\xi_{\mathrm{min}}')|+\int_{0}^{1}|f''(t)|\, dt \\ 
>   & \leq |f'(\xi_{\mathrm{min}}')|+\left(\int_{0}^{1}|f''(t)|^{p}\,dt\right)^{1/p}
>  \end{align*}
>       and by the mean-value theorem
>       \begin{align*}
>   2|f(x)|\geq |f(x)-f(\xi_{\mathrm{min}})|=|f'(\xi)||x-\xi_{\mathrm{min}}|\geq |f'(\xi_{\mathrm{min}})||x-\xi_{\mathrm{min}}|
>  \end{align*}
>       for some $\xi$ between $x$ and $\xi_{\mathrm{min}}$. Integrating this inequality yields
>       \begin{equation*}
>   \frac{|f'(\xi_{\mathrm{min}}')|}{2} = \int_{0}^{1}|f'(\xi_{\mathrm{min}}')||x-\xi_{\mathrm{min}}|\, dx\leq 2\int_{0}^{1}|f(x)|\, dx \leq 2\|f\|_{L^p}
>  \end{equation*}
>       why
>       \begin{equation*}
>   |f'(x)|\leq 4\|f\|_{L^p}+\|f''\|_{L^p} \Rightarrow \|f'\|_{L^p}\leq 4\|f\|_{L^p}+\|f''\|_{L^p}  \leq 4\|f\|_2
>  \end{equation*}

Now I don't see a way to generalise this method to the case $n>2$ using induction. For instance if we consider the case $n=3$ then applying the method to $f'$ we obtain
$$\|f'\|_{L^p} \leq 4\|f\|_{L^p}+\|f''\|_{L^p}$$
but when we do the same estimate on $f''$ we again get a term containing $f'$ so this reasoning becomes circular.

This question has been previously asked in 
[Sobolev space and equivalence of norms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108621/sobolev-space-and-equivalence-of-norms/108631).
The answer there however seems to be incomplete as it assumes that $f^{(k)}(0) = 0$ for every $k$ and the above calculation in the case that $n=2$ can be seen as a way to get around this fact using calculus.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gagliardo%E2%80%93Nirenberg_interpolation_inequality (Hope this helps)