Why is $W^n_{p}[0,1]$ a Banach space with this norm?
Let $0\leqslant p< \infty, 1\leqslant n$ and $W^n_{p}[0,1]$ be the set of all functions $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{F}$ such that $f$ has $n$ continuous derivatives and $f^{(n)}\in L^p[0,1]$, define $\left \| f\right \|=[\int_{0}^{1}\left | f(x)\right |^pdx]^{1/p}+[\int_{0}^{1}\left | f^{(n)}(x)\right |^pdx]^{1/p}$.
Can anyone tell me whether $W^n_{p}[0,1]$ is a Banach space with this norm or not?
I just stuck with the quesition Sobolev space and equivalence of norms but I can't follow the step why we can extract a weakly converging subsequence and by compactness of the embedding(I don't know anything about Sobolev space and I encountered this problem while reading Chapter 3 p67 question-14 of Conway's book)? So I just want to prove $W^n_{p}[0,1]$ is a Banach space with this norm and apply the corollary of inverse mapping theorem in order to show these two norms are equivalent.

This could help https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108621/sobolev-space-and-equivalence-of-norms?noredirect=1&lq=1
